# Explicit computation of Mellin transformation and its inverse

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, mellin-transform

Using the formula of Mellin inverse transformation, I want to obtain $f(t)$ directly from Mellin and its inverse transformation.

i.e.,
\begin{align}
f(t) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i \infty} \mathcal{M}[f;s] t^{-s} ds \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i \infty} \left(  \int_0^{\infty} f(\tau) \tau^{s-1} d\tau \right) t^{-s} ds 
\end{align}
After implementing the R.H.S, I have no idea how this becomes $f(t)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Fourier inversion formula?  It's basically the same thing

Comment: Just perform a change of variables on Fourier inversion formula and eureka

Comment: @TravorLZH, WOW it is really surprising!; without changing variables into the form of Fourier inversion formula, it seems it is not possible to deal with obtaining $f(t)$, but after changing variable it really is!

Comment: It involves a Dirac Delta integral representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be derived from Fourier inversion theorem i.e., $f= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}[f;\beta] e^{2\pi i \beta x} d\beta$. : Note that
\begin{align}
 & f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F} [f;\beta] e^{2 \pi i \beta x} d \beta  \quad \Rightarrow \quad
  f(e^{-x}) e^{-ax} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(s) e^{2\pi i\beta x} d \beta   \\
    &\quad \Rightarrow \quad f(t) = t^{-a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(s) t^{-2 \pi i \beta} d\beta = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{a-i \infty}^{a+i \infty} F(s) t^{-s} ds
\end{align}